# Math domain error in fermat

Tags: python

```
from math import sqrt

def fermatBook (n):
    x=int(sqrt(n))
    c=x**2-n
    while (sqrt(c)!=int(sqrt(c))):
        x=x+1
    y=sqrt(c)
    a=x+y
    b=x-y
    if a==1 or b==1:
        print "The number is prime"
    return a, b
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    fermatBook (23867)
  File "C:/Python27/fermatLivro.py", line 6, in fermatBook
    while (sqrt(c)!=int(sqrt(c))):
ValueError: math domain error
```

I don't know what is going wrong with the program... Could someone help me ?

Comment: And neither do we without the error message.

Comment: What's the error/the problem?

Comment: `c` is (pretty much) always negative since `int(sqrt(n)) <= sqrt(n)` and thus `int(sqrt(n))**2 <= n`

Comment: Also `while (sqrt(c)!=int(sqrt(c))): x=x+1` will never end, once you enter it.

Comment: Could you post which primality test you are trying to implement. I don't know this one and I am really intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

most likely your variable c is going negative:

Example

if you call:

```
n = 2 
fermatBook(n)
```

it will assign the following values to the following variables:

```
x = int(sqrt(n)) = int(1.47...) = 1
c = x**2 - n = 1**2 - 2 = 1 - 2 = -1
```

This will likely happen alot on values of `n` whose square root is not an integer.

```
sqrt(n) >= int(sqrt(n)), n >= 0
```

Then when you call `sqrt(c)` it is out of the domain because it cannot handle negative values.

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

You should rather use something that can handle imaginary numbers, i.e. [`cmath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html)

Or perform checks to assure this does not happen:

As an example...

```
if c < 0:
    c = 0
```

As soon as you fix this however you are going to run into another problem:

This is an infinite loop:

```
while (sqrt(c)!=int(sqrt(c))):
    x=x+1
```

you need to update c otherwise the condidtion will never change no matter how many times you increment `x`.  You probably meant this?

```
while (sqrt(c)!=int(sqrt(c))):
    x=x+1
    c = x**2+n # <--- UPDATE c
```